# why mvm package to make springboot fat jar works for parent but not working for dependencyManagment

Tags: maven

I want to just use mvn package to make springboot fat jar but for below pom setting
mvn package works to create springboot fat jar

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.0.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath/> 
</parent>
```

for below pom setting, mvn package does not create springboot fat jar, i have to use mvn package spring-boot:repackage, why is that ? any hints will be more
than welcome!

```
<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <!-- Spring Boot BOM -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-dependencies</artifactId>
            <version>${springboot.version}</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
        </dependency>
      </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>
```

Comment: If you use the spring-boot-dependencies import you have to configure the spring-boot-maven-plugin ...is described in the docs..

Comment: I checked spring-boot-starter-parent/pom.xml  ( https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/master/spring-boot-project/spring-boot-starters/spring-boot-starter-parent/pom.xml ) it has <pluginManagement> parts for plugins, it seems those plugins will be automatically imported into my project, if i  use spring-boot-starter-parent as parent of my project.